# Metric and Sup norm

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Can anyone check my proof for me? Thanks!

Let $(X,d)$ be metric space, and define $f_x(y)=d(x,y)$ show that $f_x=||f_x-f_y||$, where $||.||=\sup\{|f_x(y)|:y\in X\}$ .

Proof:
So I have to show $f_x(y)\geq ||f_x-f_y||$ and $||f_x-f_y||\geq f_x(y)$. If $||f_x-f_y||=\pm\infty \implies f_x=\pm\infty$ and we are done.

Consider $||f_x-f_y||<\infty$, then $||f_x-f_y||\geq |f_x(y)-f_y(y)|=|f_x(y)|$. Conversely, $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)\implies d(x,y)\geq d(x,z)-d(y,z)$, since $||f_x-f_y||$ is the supreme, we must have $d(x,y)\geq ||f_x-f_y||$.  Hence $||f_x-f_y||=f_x(y)$.

Comment: Why is $\|f_x(z)\| \ge f_x(y)$?  And you should probably add some more details to the converse direction.

Comment: For the statement $f_x = \|f_x-f_y\|$, are you saying $f_x(y) = \|f_x-f_y\|$?

Comment: @user6247850 Hi thanks!, $||f_x(z)||=\sup\{|f(z)|: z \in X\}$ , since $y\in X$, we have the inequality hold?

Comment: @Remu You fixed $z \in X$ such that $f_y(z) = 0$, so now $f_x(z)$ is just a number.  $\|f_x\| = \sup \{|f_x(a)| : a \in X\}$, but $\|f_x(z)\|$ isn't really well-defined because the norm is defined for functions, not numbers.  It could be thought of as taking $f_x(z)$ times a function which is identically $1$, but then we just have $\|f_x(z)\| = f_x(z)$.

Comment: @user6247850 I see that makes sense! what about this inequality $||f_x-f_y||\geq |f_x(y)-f_y(y)|=|f_x(y)|$

Comment: @Remu Yes, that looks good.  I agree with the proof you have now.

Comment: $f_x$ is a function, one that cannot be constant unless $X$ has only one point. $\|f_x - f_y\|$ is a number. Thus $f_x = \|f_x - f_y\|$ is false. From your proof, it looks like it should be $f_x(y) = \|f_x - f_y\|$, or after parsing the definitions: $d(x,y) = \sup_{z \in X} |d(x,z) - d(y,z)|$. Note that all numbers here are necessarily positive, so there is never going be anything $= -\infty$. You need to expand on why $\|f_x - f_y\| = \infty \implies f_x(y) = \infty$ (again, $f_x$ is a non-constant function, so it cannot be $=\infty$).