# Proof help for real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $g_x=f_x-f_a$, where a is fixed and $f_x(y)=d(x,y)$. Show that the map $x\mapsto g_x$ is a distance preserving embedding of X into the normed space of bounded functions on X.

Here is how far I've been able to proceed with the proof:

Let $x,y \in X$, then $d(x,y)=||f_x-f_y||=||(f_x-f_a)-(f_y-f_a)||$ for fixed $a\in X$, hence we have $d(x,y)=||g_x-g_y||$. This shows $x \mapsto g_x$ is distance preserving.

Now to show $||g_x||<M$ for some $M>0$, consider $||g_x||=||f_x-f_a||=d(x,a)$, I want to say $d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)\leq ||f_x-f_y||+||f_y-f_a||$. Not sure If I'm on the right path since I can't see a way to say this bounded.

Comment: Why does $d(x,y)=||f_x-f_y||$? It is true, but it is an important part of the proof so it helps to write it down carefully.

Furthermore, once that has been established then $||g_x||=||f_x-f_a||=d(x,a)$ as you argued and then $||g_x||=d(x,a)<\infty$ so $g_x$ is bounded, and there is no need to argue further.

Note that to show that $x\mapsto g_x$ is an embedding you would need to show (or note) that $g$ is injective. Why is this the case?

Comment: This question may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314001/the-space-of-continuous-bounded-functions-from-a-metric-space-x-to-mathbb-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The space of continuous, bounded functions from a metric space $X$ to $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314001/the-space-of-continuous-bounded-functions-from-a-metric-space-x-to-mathbb-r)

Comment: @NicolasAgote Thank you for the comments! I did prove the equality over here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545242/metric-and-sup-norm . But after reading through the links I am still a bit confused on why $d(x, a)$ is bounded. since a is fixed, but nothing implies that $d(x,a)$ needs to be finite. Or I am missing something.

Comment: $x$ is also fixed when calculating $||g_x||$ so $d(x,a)$ is just a real number.

Comment: @NicolasAgote A really dumb question, even if x is fixed, how do I know the distance between x and a is finite? I mean why cant they be infinite distant away? Thanks!

Comment: By definition, a metric's image is a subset of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, so the distance will necessarily be a non-negative real number and then it will be finite.